# Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.8.8, trying next server [ubuntu 14.04 digitalocean ispconfig]

Tags: 14.04, server, dns, bind, hostname

All started with a vps from digitalocean and the following documentation from ispconfig https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-apache2-php-mysql-pureftpd-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3 after all the installation process, i added my domain trough ispconfig interface and updated my domain nameservers with the one created by ispconfig.

My problem that i can not find a solution to it, when i try nslookup crisubogdan.com i get the following error:

```
root@sv:~# nslookup crisubogdan.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.8.8, trying next server
Server:         8.8.4.4
Address:        8.8.4.4#53

** server can't find crisubogdan.com: SERVFAIL
```

And when i try dig crisubogdan.com i get the following error:

```
root@sv:~# dig crisubogdan.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> crisubogdan.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 46265
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;crisubogdan.com.               IN      A

;; Query time: 3028 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 16 14:12:45 EST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

Some info about bind:

/etc/bind/named.conf code:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.options code:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //      0.0.0.0;
    // };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    // dnssec-validation auto;
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.local code:

```
zone "crisubogdan.com" {
    type master;
    allow-transfer {none;};
    file "/etc/bind/pri.crisubogdan.com";
};
zone "craftedfreebies.com" {
    type master;
    allow-transfer {none;};
    file "/etc/bind/pri.craftedfreebies.com";
};
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones code:

```
// prime the server with knowledge of the root servers
zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};

// be authoritative for the localhost forward and reverse zones, and for
// broadcast zones as per RFC 1912

zone "localhost" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};
```

/etc/bind/pri.crisubogdan.com code:

```
$TTL        3600
@       IN      SOA     ns1.crisubogdan.com. contact.crisubogdan.com. (
                        2015020808       ; serial, todays date + todays serial #
                        7200              ; refresh, seconds
                        540              ; retry, seconds
                        604800              ; expire, seconds
                        86400 )            ; minimum, seconds
;

crisubogdan.com. 3600 A        178.62.241.109
mail 3600 A        178.62.241.109
ns1.crisubogdan.com. 3600 A        178.62.241.109
ns2.crisubogdan.com. 3600 A        178.62.241.109
www 3600 A        178.62.241.109
crisubogdan.com. 3600      MX    10   mail.crisubogdan.com.
crisubogdan.com. 3600      NS        ns1.crisubogdan.com.
crisubogdan.com. 3600      NS        ns2.crisubogdan.com.
```

/etc/resolv.conf code:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I don't know why this errors are made and if you can please me help me end my almost 8 days of struggle with my vps bind error.

Thanks.

Comment: Run `nslookup crisubogdan.com 127.0.0.1`.  If that reports correctly, then I'm assuming you haven't set up your nameservers properly at your registrar.

Comment: This is the report: root@sv:~# nslookup crisubogdan.com 127.0.0.1
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   crisubogdan.com
Address: 178.62.241.109

Comment: So named is working correctly.  The issue is most likely at your domain registrar.  Did you register ns1/ns2 and point your domain towards them?

Comment: Yes, https://www.whois.net/ display ns1.crisubogdan.com and ns2.crisubogdan.com

Comment: Did you register those as nameservers?

Comment: So i added ns1.crisubogdan.com and ns2.crisubogdan.com to my domain, by registering do you mean the register nameserver function where you add the nameservers lik ns1.crisubogdan.com IP, ns2.crisubogdan.com IP. ? And also i want to thank you for your help.

Comment: At your domain registrar, there should be an option to register nameservers.  It depends on the registrar where the option is or what steps to take, but that is necessary otherwise your nameserver addresses won't work.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, my guess is you didn't complete that step.  It is best to google instructions based on your registrar.

Comment: I registered my nameservers and everything seems to work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments.  The OP needed to register the nameservers at their domain registrar.

The OP was able to confirm the BIND server was reporting the correct DNS information:

`nslookup crisubogdan.com 127.0.0.1`

This runs a lookup at 127.0.0.1 (localhost).  Since this reported correctly, the problem was most likely at the registrar with either the nameservers not being registered or the domain not using the correct nameservers.